# Send a file to an API from Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I need to take the current active document open in photoshop and send it to a JS function who need the file in parameter.

I tried by getting the path of the file like this :

```
csInterface.evalScript('app.documents[0].fullName.parent.fsName.toString()',function(result){
    csInterface.evalScript('app.documents[0].name', function(res) {
      var response = result+"/"+res;
      var path = response.replace(/\\/g, '/');
      console.log(path);
      var file = window.cep.fs.readFile(path);
      console.log(file);
      //projectCreateDownloadToken(file.data);
    });
```

and then use window.cep.fs.readFile to get the file from the path but it only take the data and not the file.

Maybe I need to use

```
 var arg = 'file=@'+path;
  var url ="your_server_url ";
  console.log(window.cep.process.createProcess('/usr/bin/curl','--form',arg,url));
```

But I'm looking for an other solution. Thank you for any helps !

[image: Result I have atm]

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the file'? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I'm trying to put the document open in photoshop on a server. So I need to have a javascript file object wich contain the current active document in photoshop

Comment: in first two lines you're getting a folder where the first document in PS is located and then  in another script you're getting it's name... what's the point of `result+"/"+res` if you can get a path to file with `activeDocument.fullName`?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy the name of the document is not in the fullname, he just give the directory where the file is located so i had to do this to have the full absolute path of the document

Comment: you're wrong, `activeDocument.fullName` gives you the full path. In your code you use only the folder because you use `.parent` — so you're going one level up

Comment: yes but it gives with a path like ~/Desktop and when it search the file with cs readFile, it search with relative path. Here it search with absolute and i can reach the data of the document @SergeyKritskiy

Comment: ...and that's what `.fsName` property is for, it gives a full OS path: https://i.imgur.com/YZGQmsj.png

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy with the fullName properties i got this : https://imgur.com/FuiFz6f and with the fsName properties i got this : https://imgur.com/a/Ghc6gLo

Comment: on your second screenshot, were you doing `activeDocument.fullName.fsName`?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy ha no, it works ! Now that i have the fullpath, how can i get a file object  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228307/discussion-between-laurent-q-and-sergey-kritskiy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using this code

```
csInterface.evalScript('app.documents[0].fullName.fsName', function(res) {
      let fileInBase64 = window.cep.fs.readFile(res, cep.encoding.Base64);
      let fileName =  res.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
      urltoFile('data:image/png;base64,'+fileInBase64.data, fileName)
      .then(function(file){
        //do what you want with the file
      });
    });
  }, false);
```